# Free-body diagram for a collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision, free-body-diagram

**Edit -** Consider an homogeneous bar of length $L$ and mass $M$. This bar can rotate on a horizontal plane with no friction around a point $A$. The distance between $A$ and the center $O$ of the bar is $a$.
Since we are on a plane, the gravity is not working.

Suppose that this bar is rotating with constant angular velocity $\omega_0$.

Moreover, suppose that this bar hits a mass $m$ in a point $B$. The distance between $B$ and the center $O$ is $b$. Regardless the nature of the collision (elastic or inelastic), I was told that linear momentum is not conserved while angular momentum is.

The explanation I received is the following: during the collisions, an impulsive force arises on the fulcrum in $A$; this force is external and hence the linear momentum is not conserved, while the angular one is conserved since this impulsive force does not produce torque in $A$.

This explanation does not convince me totally.

I post a picture.
[image]

I would like to figure out which are the forces that arises during the collisions. Moreover, I would like to know in which points they act.

Comment: "F1+F2=0" is not a sensible statement as each acts on a different body.  It looks like Newton's 3rd law but one cannot add forces acting on different objects to predict anything about the system.  Also, you need to include the force on the rod due to the axis at A.  As for the torque and axis force.  Why do you expect that the force acting on A is in the x-direction?  This could be part normal force (contact between touching surfaces) and friction.  If the hinge is frictionless the force will point along a line through the center point (cross product = 0).

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: @ggcg no, it isn't. It is just a setup that I don't understand after the mechanics course.

Comment: see my comment above.  I think some of your initial statements are inconsistent with the picture, hence the confusion.  Also, the axis is mounted to something big and rigid, wall or table, building, planet.  This is a mental construct to create an inertial bath (my own pet name following the notion of a thermal bath).

Comment: @ggcg ok, let's start again. Which are the (impulsive) forces that arises during the collision? In which points they act? $F_1$ and $F_2$ are just a (surely wrong) attempt to answer to this question.

Comment: Consider a thin space between the inner edge of the hole in the rod and the axis (if that helps).  The small mass hits the rod.  In an instant (infinitesimal duration) the rod hits the axis (from below).  Being circular in cross section (otherwise I can't imagine it being effective) and frictionless the impulsive force between the rod and axis points through the center of the axis.  If the problem were ideal it would take the limit as the rod is 1-dim and axis 0-dim.

Comment: A more realistic treatment leads to the contact force acting through the center of the axis of rotation --> no cross product and no torque.  The point of contact is somewhere in the circle that surrounds the point A.

Comment: @ggcg the idea of the "thin space" helps me a lot, thanks! Then, the rod is subject to two forces, one due to the collision with the small mass and one due to the collision with the axis. What can we say about the magnitude of these forces?

Comment: If I can find time I may post a complete solution.  But in the mean time think of whether you can determine the force at the axis (that the axis exerts on the rod) after the collision and when the rod is rotating.  That process may illuminate how to analyze the impulse case.

Comment: Also, one of my comments is not correct.  When I say that the impulse at the axis is from below that isn't true (always).  It depends on where the small mass hits the rod.  For example, if it hits at the CoM then the rod will move down and the axis impulse will be up.  Etc.

Comment: This is a Pendelum that rotate around point A $\varphi$ is the rotation angle

Comment: @Eli not properly. The rod and the mass lie on a plane, so gravity has no effect on the motion.

Comment: @Eli, It is not a pendulum problem, and even if it were that doesn't answer the question of what happens at the hinge which is the item of interest.   To the_candyman, to a physicist it's enough to accept that it's a holonomic constraint but I like your question as it should be possible to determine the stress in the joint.  I think I have addressed your initial question "why is the torque zero", but consider understanding what happens at the joint an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

I try to solve this problem exactly 
\begin{align*}
  &\text{I)  The EOM's bevor impact:} \\\\
  M\,L\,\ddot{\varphi}&=\cos(\varphi)\left(F_2+M\,g\right)\\
  m\,\ddot{y}&=F_1-m\,g
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  &\text{II)  The EOM's after impact:} \\\\
  M\,L\,\ddot{\varphi}&=\cos(\varphi)\left(F_2+M\,g-F_c\right)\,,&(1)\\
  m\,\ddot{y}&=F_1-m\,g+F_c\,,\quad& (2)\\
  \tan(\varphi)&=\frac{y}{b}\,,\quad \text{The impact condition}  &(3)
\end{align*}
So we habe three equations for three unknowns

$\ddot{\varphi}\,,\quad \ddot{y}\,\quad$  and the impact force   $F_c$

**Results**:

\begin{align*}
    \ddot{y}&=\frac{2\,\dot{y}^2\,y}{1+y^2}\,,\quad y(0)=h_0\,,\quad D(y)(0)=0\\
    \ddot{\varphi}&=f(y,\dot{y}\,,F_1\,,F_2\,,b)\\
 F_c&=M\,g+\frac{M}{1+y^2}\left(2\,\dot{y}^2\,y\right)+F_1
  \end{align*}
The EOM's don't depent on the  "geometry parameter $a$" !!

I hope it is helpful for you ?

Comment: I think the rod is on a horizontal table, hence gravity is cancelled by Normal force.

Comment: So you can put g=0 on the equations

Comment: It seems that there may be errors in your angular equation.  How is phi defined and where are your lever arms?